# How to run shell script by using aws command?

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-ec2

In a Linux ec2 machine has **test.sh** created.

```
echo "Hello World" > txt
```

i want to run this script by using aws command in command prompt. i tried below solution but nothing happen.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-16d4986e --user-data file:////home/ubuntu/test.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

That command creates an entirely new instance, and runs that script at startup.

If you you want to run your script on an existing instance you should look into the [EC2 Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/) service.

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply. Can you give an example command? It's very easy to me to understand.

Comment: It's not just a command, you have to setup the service first. I suggest you read the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/execute-remote-commands.html